# Mailchimp - Redirect to thank you page

Tags: mailchimp

I am using Mail Chimp and in one of my forms when someone registers via custom form, a message appears at the bottom saying 'Check your email for a confirmation email' or something like that. I would like to have them redirect to a thank you page (the standard one will do) instead of a message just appearing, I have been banging my head against a wall trying to figure this out, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.....any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating an embedded form, be sure to disable javascript. There is a check box for it.

Comment: This does not work. It causes the page to redirect to the hosted version of the form.

Comment: Edit: this does actually work  - see my answer below for full explanation

Comment: @user979331 how I can get user FNAME and LNAME after submitted and redirected on the thanks page?

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is very vague and doesn't explain fully the process which is explained here in the Mailchimp docs:

https://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/design-and-host-your-own-thank-you-pages

If you check the 'disable all javascript' option then you'll need to perform your own form validation to avoid the form redirecting to a Mailchimp-hosted version of the form if there are errors. Then, once you have submitted the form, it will redirect to your chosen URL.

Comment: can I stop opening confirmation/thank you page on new tab?