# Mailchimp - Redirect to thank you page with embedded form

Tags: mailchimp

I followed the following post but the redirection is still not effective ...
[Mailchimp - Redirect to thank you page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489614/mailchimp-redirect-to-thank-you-page)

I can't find a way to make it work. The embedded form is embedded here on [my website](https://www.travel-homes.com/doneeng.html):

And the html code is:

```
  <!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
    <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
        #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
        /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
           We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
    </style>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="https://travel-homes.us18.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=ab5689b8019de3c007fe4634b&amp;id=84b4167b78" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
        <h2>Main Guest</h2>
    <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    </label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="required" id="mce-LNAME">
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    </label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">E-mail  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
    </label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
    </div>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
        <label for="mce-group[2217]">Apartment </label>
        <select name="group[2217]" class="REQ_CSS" id="mce-group[2217]">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Le Wilson</option>
    <option value="2">Le Rebberg</option>
    <option value="4">Le Bright'n Cosy|Comfy Studio - City Center</option>
    <option value="8">L'Alsacien</option>
    <option value="16">L'EastSide</option>
    <option value="32">Le Pfeffel</option>
    <option value="128">Le Bredele</option>
    <option value="256">Colmar Unique Apartment</option>

        </select>
    </div>
        <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
        </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_ab5689b8019de3c007fe4634b_84b4167b78" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
        <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Send" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>

    <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

I hope somebody can find a solution to this unsolvable issue.

Comment: Have you setup Thank You page in form settings in MailChimp ? [Embedded form](https://mailchimp.com/help/design-and-host-your-own-thank-you-pages/)

Comment: Yes Mr Akbar. And I setup the redirection as well.